# Mapping always returning null

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, moq, handler

Line **var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel)**; gives error
job variable is always returning null while running the unit test
i have added the mapping for Jobs Profile `

Below is the code:

JobTest.cs class

```
public class JobTests
    {
        private static Mock<IMapper> _mapper;
     
     
        public JobTests()
        {
            if (_mapper == null)
            {
                _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
                _mapper.Setup(x => x.ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid());
                _mapper.Setup(x => x.ConfigurationProvider)
                    .Returns(
                        () => new MapperConfiguration(
                            cfg =>
                            {
                                cfg.AddProfile<JobsProfile>();
                               
                                //cfg.CreateMap<AddJobCommand,JobsProfile > ();
                                //cfg.CreateMap<JobViewModel, AddJobCommand>();
                                //cfg.CreateMap<AddJobCommand,JobViewModel>();

                            }));
                
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task AddJob_AddSingleEntry()
        {

            var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
            
            var data = JobData.AddFakeJobList();           
            var mockSet = FakeDbSetup.GetMockDbSet<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(data);           
           
            var mockContext = FakeDbSetup.GetMockDbContext();            
            mockSet.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
            mockContext.Setup(c => c.Jobs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

         

            AddJobCommandHandler handler = new AddJobCommandHandler(mockContext.Object, _mapper.Object);
            JobViewModel vm= JobData.AddFakeJobList2();
            AddJobCommand command = new AddJobCommand(vm);
            //var stubScheduleCommand = new Mock<AddJobCommand>(mockContext.Object);           
            
            var job = await handler.Handle(command, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
            Assert.NotNull(job);
            }
        

    }
```

AddJobCommand.cs

```
public class AddJobCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<AddJobCommand, JobViewModel>
    {
        private readonly IDrillingFluidsContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public AddJobCommandHandler(IDrillingFluidsContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            (_context, _mapper) = (context, mapper);
        }

        public async Task<JobViewModel> Handle(AddJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (command.JobViewModel == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty request.");
            var jobViewModel = command.JobViewModel;
          
            try
            {
                var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
                
                _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().Add(job);
                if (job.Notes!= null)
                { 
                    var newNote = job.Notes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IsNew);
                    if (newNote != null)
                    {
                        newNote.JobId = job.Id;
                        _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.JobNote>().Attach(newNote);
                        _context.Entry(newNote).State = EntityState.Added;
                    }
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(job.Name))
                {
                    job.Name = await GenerateJobName(job);                   
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                jobViewModel.Id = job.Id;
                return jobViewModel;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I want the JobViewModel data to be added to the the variable jobs.But it always returns null.This works fine when i am trying to call this method via PostMan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code uses a mocked mapper that has no setup for the `Map` method. If there is no setup, the method will return null (for
MockBehavior.Loose`).

If you want the `Map` method to return a value, you need add a setup, e.g.:

```
[Fact]
public async Task AddJob_AddSingleEntry()
{        
    var data = JobData.AddFakeJobList();           
    var mockSet = FakeDbSetup.GetMockDbSet<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(data);           
    var mockContext = FakeDbSetup.GetMockDbContext();            
    mockSet.Setup(x => x.AsNoTracking()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Jobs).Returns(mockSet.Object);

    AddJobCommandHandler handler = new AddJobCommandHandler(mockContext.Object, _mapper.Object);
    JobViewModel vm= JobData.AddFakeJobList2();
    AddJobCommand command = new AddJobCommand(vm);
    //var stubScheduleCommand = new Mock<AddJobCommand>(mockContext.Object);
    var job = new DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job() 
    {
      // Initialize job as needed
    };           

    _mapper.Setup(x => x.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(vm))
      .Returns(job);
    
    var job = await handler.Handle(command, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
    Assert.NotNull(job);
}
```

In the constructor it is not necessary to add setups for the configuration provider if you are using a mocked mapper. So you can setup the `_mapper` simply like this:

```
public JobTests()
{
    _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
}
```

Comment: I have added the setup and have added some values to job variable. Now when it calls the handle method ,I am getting "Object reference not set to instance of an object error"  on below line in my AddJobCommand.cs file.   
                
                _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().Add(job);

Comment: The context is also a mock. You need to add the setups exactly as they are called in the code under test. `_context.Jobs` != `_context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>()`.

Comment: I did not get the above statement _context.Jobs != _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>()

Comment: I meant the `Setup`; the `NullReferenceException` is probably raised because there is no setup for `_context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>()`. If Moq does not find a setup, it returns null, hence the error. I saw that there is a setup for `_context.Jobs`, but this is not used in the code.